# How can I make the text below an image the same size as the image with the same border?

Tags: image, css, background, border, caption

I am trying to have an image with caption be the same size.  Instead of having the caption be centered under the image I want the caption to be the same size as the image.

Here is the CSS for the image:

```
        article.post 
       .wp-caption img, 
        article.page .wp-caption img {
        border: 2px solid white; 
            outline: 8px solid rgb(245, 222, 179);
        }
```

Here is the CSS for the caption:

```
        article.post .wp-caption, 
        article.page .wp-caption {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        background: none;
        }
```

If you want an example of the page here it is:
http://www.metnews.org/news/aurora-remembers-holmes-victims/

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add together the width of the image as well as any padding/margins in use and then set the container element of the text to the same width.